# Dual relationship to model with one polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scenario where I have two models "group" and "motion".
A group may have many motions and every motion is related to a group.
A motion may also be related to one of various models of which group may be one.

So I have a has_many relationship between Group & Motion and a polymorphic relationship between Motion & Group.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :motions
  has_many :motions, as: :motionable
end

class Motion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group  
  belongs_to :motionable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Whilst this appears to work a new record in motions creates the polymorphic relationship whereas I require the has_many relationship:

```
2.4.1 :010 > Group.first.motions.new
  Group Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" ORDER BY "groups"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Motion id: nil, group_id: nil, motionable_type: "Group", motionable_id: 1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working now using the following:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :motions
  has_many :subjects, class_name: "Motion", as: :motionable
end

class Motion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group  
  belongs_to :motionable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I picked this up from the following:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

I can now create the has_many relationship using:

```
Group.first.motions.new
```

and the polymorphic relationship using:

```
Group.first.subjects.new
```